# Java UIManager - What's the name of the area around a button

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel, uimanager

I'm using the Windows XP look and feel.  On a panel containing a button there is a rectangular area around a button that looks like the area that a classic button would take up.  That area is not adhering to the color of my panel.  For example I'm setting my panel to blue but the area around the button is still white.  What is the name of that area.  I've tried button.shadow but that's not it.

Thanks
ST

Comment: be a little more specific, are you asking about the color of the shadow ?

Answer (score 1):

Not all properties are controlled by the UIManager. You can use [UIManager Defaults](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/09/uimanager-defaults/) to see if you can find the property you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried that.  I've found that the upper shadow is called Button.shadow.  I've changed that.  There's still a 1px white outline of my button.  It displays on the lower right portion of the button.  Nothing I change seems to correct it.  I've spit out all UIManager properties and am not having any luck.

Answer (score 1):

With an example it is hard to know for sure.  What about: `button.border` or `button.darkshadow`.

Comment: Is there a list somewhere of all options available for buttons?  Those didn't work either.  Is there a way to post an image here?

Comment: Yes you can post an image.  camickr's link has a good list.  Maybe you are dealing with some other border?

Comment: I just did some more testing.  It looks like it's the gradient of the button border or something like that.  I'll keep playing.  Thanks for the help.